# jquery 2 plugins breaking each other... which, and why?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and am using 2 plugins together.

http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs
^ For a flip effect when the page loads and mouseover flip effect.

And rcarousel, which I can't post a link to because I'm new.

Basically, the effect is this:

- Page loads, all of the tiles should flip/animate.
- Any mouseover should cause the tile to flip again (currently for testing purpose, they all flip at the same time, twice, then stop, and then flip on mouesover).
- Carousel will be sitting in a header and requires user interaction to scroll through the rest of the tiles.

They work fine together when the page first loads ... but once you press Left or Right arrow on the carousel, the animation no longer functions, neither if I change the repeat back to infinite nor on mouseover.

http://www.elevation24.com/newtiles

Thanks for any assistance, please be gentle :) I realize everything is likely quite convoluted and messy... I have no idea what I am doing and am amazed I have gotten this far :D

Answer (score 0):

When you load the new 'flipboxes' you'll have to call the 'flip-script' again...

Would be easiest, if you make a function for them

```
function loadFlip(){
    $(".live-tile").hover(function(){
        $(this).liveTile("animate");
    });
}
```

Call this function everytime you click the prev or next link.. :]